# How to gather attribute of a wordpress page on a outside page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new at Wordpress. I'm making a site, and i'm making it directly on code. Perhaps, i have a doubt: Let's say i have on my blog (site.com/blog) a attribute that is, for example, street-location.

I'm on my home page, and i want to do a "blog" section, where i will only show the most relevant news of the blog external page. For example:

```
<h1> this is the news from the street <?php bloginfo = 'street-location'?> </h1>
```

Example: I have a real estate theme. There are many things composing the building, including, on the same example, street-location. On the buildings page, i'll set some street adress to "street-location", and that will be INSIDE Wordpress.

What i need to know is: OUTSIDE Wordpress (if i create an external folder, for example), how can i get this attribute?

Do it work like i described above? How do i link this?

Wait for the answer, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. You say `attribute`. Is that a HTML attribute? Or do you mean a tag or category? Or something entirely different?

Comment: Exactly! A category!

I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `WP_Query` to find the relevant posts.

```
$query = new WP_Query(['category_name' => 'street-location']);

<?php if ($query->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post() ?>
        <h2><?= get_the_title($query->post->ID) ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata() ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Read the documentation for details of the other available query arguments. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks! That's what i was looking for.